# After auto update, Samsung Tab S2 will not reconnect to Samsung Tab S2 9.7 bluetooth keyboard

Tags: samsung, keyboard, bluetooth

My Samsung tab S2 had an auto update yesterday. Now, the matching samsung bluetooth keyboard will not reconnect. When I try it comes up with "unable to connect" message.  Keyboard still shows as paired. Tried On/Off Bluetooth and reboot of tablet. Nothing. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on 6/13/16 with my Samsung Tab S2 and matching Samsung keyboard. In my case, the auto-update had apparently made the keyboard unrecognizable to the tablet. I decided to re-pair the keyboard with the tablet. To make the keyboard 'discoverable' by the tablet during its scan of nearby devices, I pressed and held the Bluetooth function key on the keyboard (which = F11 on my keyboard) until the keyboard signaled OK by flashing its blue-green-red light pattern. Once the keyboard was in that state, the tablet could discover the keyboard as a Bluetooth device and connect to it. Hope this helps!

Comment: than you, it help. i click fn+f11, but not only f11. That was be big probem but now its working. very, very thank you